# String containing arabic and variables

Tags: android, xml, string, variables, arabic

I wanted to translate the following string in arabic for my Android app: "You and your friends have played for %1$d and have won %2$d pts overall" by copy/pasting the arabic translation in my XML then typing the variables by hand.
The problem I get is that as I type the variable is separated and typed at the end of the arabic string:

لقد لعبت أنت وأصدقاؤك لمدة %1$d وحصلتم علي %2$d من إجمالي النقاط

It's weird because when I type it separately, it looks okay: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzDZy.png
but when I copy/paste it in the XML file it's broken: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U63B9.png

What can I do to avoid that?

Thanks

SOLVED: We added LTR unicode markers in front of variables

Answer (score 0):

this is normal in Arabic text so to avoid that split the string this way
لقد لعبت أنت وأصدقاؤك لمدة 
d$1%
وحصلتم على 
d$2% 
من أجمالي النقاط
then re arrange them by putting tab space between each part , and reduce the space to reach the below result 
now copy paste the below into your XML and it should work fine,i know its long way but this is how it solved

من أجمالي النقاط d$2% وحصلتم على d$1% لقد لعبت أنت وأصدقاؤك لمدة

Comment: Close enough! =) Actually I had to type the variable from left to right so Eclipse could build it. After a few tries and putting tabs a bit randomly, I finally managed to do it!

But why is this normal? I had to put tabs around the variables (I guess it is to return in left to right typing) but also at the end of the sentence which is not obvious!

Comment: We are facing even bigger problems when it comes to development with Arabic content,unfortunately its all solved with such workarounds,in your particular problem,yes its left to right typing and mixing other languages or special characters with Arabic,some special chatterers in Arabic have problems as some letters should be linked together and others should not :)

Comment: Ok… My problem is not solved, it was ok when I edited my string in TextMate but it was still broken when I opened it in Eclipse. The app compiled but it crashed due to the broken variable. Thus I tried to edit the string directly in Eclipse but I didn't manage to make it work :(

Comment: its fine no worries, please make sure you have this in your XML :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
also click in any java file in the project , select edit from menu,then set encoding to UTF-8 
these configuration should be there when you use Arabic

Comment: Everything is set in UTF-8. I really think it's because of the variable because in the other strings containing a variable it's written LTR (%1$d)